# Update ObservableCollection item and related view, when the item implements an interface

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection, community-toolkit-mvvm

As written everywhere (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45888690/5480409), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21050642/5480409), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359646/5480409), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72460664/5480409)...), reporting an `ObservableCollection` item property change to a view requires the item to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Using [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) this can be done using an attribute:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection { get; set; }
    //...
}

[INotifyPropertyChanged] // yay! No boilerplate code needed
public partial class MyItem
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If somewhere inside `MyViewModel` there is a change to the `MyProperty` of an item of `MyCollection`, the view will be updated.
What if an interface comes into play?

```cs
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<IMyInterface> MyCollection { get; set; }
    //...
}

[INotifyPropertyChanged]
public partial class MyItem : IMyInterface // MyProperty is in IMyInterface too
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The view seems not to be updated anymore.
I tried:

1. Inheriting `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `IMyInterface` (that requires explicit implementation of the `PropertyChanged` event and `OnPropertyMethod` method in `MyItem`, which I don't want as otherwise I would have not used CommunityToolkit.Mvvm)
2. Adding `[INotifyPropertyChanged]` to `MyViewModel` (expecting nothing but there was an answer somewhere telling that)

Is there an obvious, no-boilerplate solution that I'm missing here?

The view is updated if I do something like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59473946/5480409)

```cs
var item = MyCollection[0];
item.MyProperty = "new value";
MyCollection[0] = item;
```

but I hope there's a better way.

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to work ok for me. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will solve your issue but I can see you're using the attribute incorrectly.

Please see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/inotifypropertychanged

"These attributes are only meant to be used in cases where the target types cannot just inherit from the equivalent types (eg. from ObservableObject). If that is possible, inheriting is the recommended approach, as it will reduce the binary size by avoiding creating duplicated code into the final assembly."

You're not inheriting from  IMyInterface, you're implementing it.

Your viewmodel should inherit ObservableObject

Instead of

```
 [INotifyPropertyChanged]
 public partial class MyItem : IMyInterface
```

You should have:

```
 public partial class MyItem : ObservableObject, IMyInterface
```

Properties look like:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<FlatTransactionVM> transactions = new List<FlatTransactionVM>();
```

That generates a public Transactions property.

If you only have properties, you don't need that to be a partial class. That's necessary for relaycommand generation.

**EDIT**

This works for me:

MainWindow

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
             DisplayMemberPath="MyProperty"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel

```
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<IMyInterface> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<IMyInterface>();
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
           MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<IMyInterface>(
              new List<MyItem>{
                  new MyItem{ MyProperty = "A" },
                  new MyItem { MyProperty = "B" },
                  new MyItem { MyProperty = "C" }
              });
        }
    }
```

MyItem

```
public partial class MyItem : ObservableObject, IMyInterface
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string myProperty;
}
```

Interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Quick and dirty code in the view.  This is purely to see what happens when one of the MyItems.MyProperty is set.

```
    private async void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        var mw = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
        mw.MyCollection[1].MyProperty = "XXXXX";
    }
```

After a short wait, I see the second item change to XXXXX as expected.

Comment: Noted, thanks, but inheriting from ObservableObject rather than using the [INotifyPropertyChanged] attribute seems functionally equivalent, which should explain why testing this change doesn't yield new results.

Comment: Your edit works, even without marking myCollection with ObservableProperty.
So the minimal change would be inheriting from ObservableObject (or using the INotifyPropertyChanged attribute) and marking its properties with ObservableProperty (and making them private fields). Still quicker than the alternatives. Many thanks @Andy

Comment: For future readers, of course the Window_ContentRendered is not needed and serves just for demonstration purposes